# Do angels serve God out of love?

Tags: theology, malach-angel, love

There are plenty of sources that angels serve Hashem out of fear. However, are there any early sources that angels serve Hashem out of love? Is that something that humans are unique in doing?

It seems to me like it should be obvious that they do love Hashem, I just can't seem to find any source that they do.

Comment: The concept of love and fear in the context of angels is described as “approach and withdrawal” (Ratzu v’Shuv) or “ascent and descent”, like with those in Yaacov’s dream.

Comment: In H. Yesode haTorah 2:2, the Rambam defines love of God in terms of knowing God. In 2:8 he describes the great extent to which the angels know God. I don't know if anyone has made the connection explicit.

Comment: [Rabbi Immanuel Bernstein](https://www.ou.org/holidays/the-case-for-receiving-the-torah-moshes-debate-with-the-angels/) has an article “The Case for Receiving the Torah: Moshe’s Debate with the Angels”.

The article establishes that 
[A] Angels have no evil inclination.
[B] Angels did not want the Torah to exist  in the form of practical mitzvos.
[C] Angels are spiritual beings closer to  Hashem than man.

Taken together, these 3 facts suggest that serving through love is more likely than serving through fear.

Comment: Do angels even experience love?